Explain the circuit inside a rechargeable hair trimmer
I have a small, normal hair trimmer:

This is the circuit inside it:

Some information:

The batteries are two rechargeable Ni-Cd 1.2V batteries.
D1 has 0.7V forward voltage.
LED (marked with "CHARGE" on the handle) has 1.8V forward voltage.
The trimmer has a switch (called K) on the handle. It is designed so that if K is closed, then K1 and K2 are  closed. If K is opened, then K1 and K2 are open.

This is the adapter:


What is the role of R1? Why is its value so small?
What is the role of R2? How to calculate the value 1K ohm for R2? Why is it not 2.2 ohm or 10K ohm?
When the adapter is plugged in and the switch K is closed, does the motor use the energy from the batteries or directly from the adapter, in two case: batteries fully charged or empty?

Edit


"Trimmer" is a term used in electronics with reference to variable capacitors (trimmer cap) and variable resistors (trimmer pot) - generally used for setup or calibration. I've added the word "hair" into your question title and post to avoid confusion.

For future reference, "The trimmer has a switch (called K) on the handle. It is designed so that if K is closed, then K1 and K2 are closed. If K is opened, then K1 and K2 are open." would be called a dual pole single throw switch, or DPST.

Dat - Hi, Are the photos/diagram in the question all your own work, or were any copied/adapted from elsewhere? TY

@SamGibson they are all my work, I took the photos by my phone and I draw the diagram from https://www.circuit-diagram.org/editor/

@Dat - Thanks for confirming. I'll leave these comments here, so other site members can see your reply (and therefore avoid more flags concerned that images may have been copied).



What is the role of R1? Why is its value so small?

R1 limits the charging current. The power supply is 3 V nominal. Let's say the cells (2 × 1.2 V) were discharged to 1 V each then we'd have 3 V in, 0.7 V dropped across D1 and 2 V across the batteris. VR1 = 3 - 0.7 - 2 = 0.3 V.
With R1 = 2.2 Ω the charging current is limited to \$ I = \frac VR = \frac {0.3}{2.2} = 136 \ \text {mA} \$ maximum.
As the cells charge up the current will fall off quite quickly to a trickle. Generally, NiCd cells can be charged at 1/16 of their Ah capacity indefinitely.

What is the role of R2? How to calculate the value 1K ohm for R2? Why is it not 2.2 ohm or 10K ohm?

The LED will have a Vf (forward voltage drop) of about 2 V leaving 1 V across R2. The current drawn by the LED will be \$ I = \frac VR = \frac 1{1k} = 1\ \text {mA} \$. It won't be awfully bright but more than adequate with a modern high efficiency LED.

When the adapter is plugged in and the switch K is closed, does the motor use the energy from the batteries or directly from the adapter, in two case: batteries fully charged or empty?

The power supply is rated at 3.0 V but I notice you've marked it as 4.2 V on the diagram. I suspect that you measured this without any load. This is important as a cheap power supply will have significant internal resistance, meaning that the output voltage will droop to an extent depending on the load.
If the motor loads the supply enough (going through a tough beard, say) that it causes the supply voltage to drop below that of the battery then both will power the motor.
If the power supply is able to run the motor and maintain the voltage above the battery voltage then the batteries will receive some charge.

You should be able to figure this out using a multimeter. Tabulate the battery voltage and the supply voltage in the various conditions.

I want to use this hair trimmer with the adapter only. So I rebuild it. First try, I build it with only a adapter, a switch and the motor, the motor doesn't move at all. Second try,  I added a 20mF capacitor across the input voltage, the motor now can spin but without the razors attached. When I attach the razors in this second try, the motor can not spin. I don't know what to do next: add more capacitors or just change the adapter to 2000mA?

I'd say it's not intended to run off the adaptor because switching it on bypasses the charge current limiting resistor. Measure the supply voltage as you increase the load on the motor. You'll probably see that it collapses. Measure the current with a multimeter on 10 A DC range. (Be sure to put the leads back in the V & COM  sockets when finished.)

Sorry but I don't understand the part "because switching it on bypasses the charge current limiting resistor". How can I rebuild this using the adapter as the only power source? I don't want to use the batteries anymore


K1 bypasses the charge limiting resistor. 2. Just disconnect the battery.


I have disconnected the battery, only use the adapter (probaly collapsed as you said), how can I fix this? add a large capacitor or use another adapter or...?

Add the table of measurements I suggested so we have some idea what power is required.

ok...please wait

I added it. What I found out is the motor cannot run with this adapter only. When I close  K2 and open K1, adapter votage is drop to 0.1V. I think the motor can run because of the batteries. The adapter is only for the charging batteries. Maybe I just need to use another adapter if I want to get rid of the batteries.
